# Why rendering textField with Behavior takes so long

Tags: java, wicket

In my app I have listView with about 100 rows. Each rows contains textField with behaviour. Problem is that rendering this page takes too long about 2s. When I remove this behaviour then it takes just couple of ms. My question is why it takes so long and is there option how to make it faster ?

```
   add(new ListView<PlayOffGame>("games") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Game> listItem) {


            listItem.add(new TextField<String>("results").add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    // do something
                }
            }));    
        }
    });
```

UPDATE

wicket version: 1.5.9

rendering =  method onRender:

```
@Override
protected void onRender() {
    logger.debug("Render start");
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onRender();
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    logger.debug("Render: " + time + " ms");
};
```

Comment: Which Wicket version?What do you mean by "rendering" time: time to render the HTML on the server or until the page is displayed in the browser? The latter might be slowed down by the registration of all those Javascript handlers.

Comment: question updated according your questions

Comment: First: use a `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` directly: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/OnChangeAjaxBehavior.html Second: see if `setReuseItems(true)` on the ListView improves the situation: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html#setReuseItems%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

It takes long because for each `TextField` you add a line of javascript (by using `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`).

I have had some issues with `AjaxEventBehavior`. I have implemented a custom behavior on the parent that checks which child caused the event. This reduces the render time, and also the browser loading time significantly.

I think it would be possible to do something similar for the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` by overriding the `onEvent` and getting the correct child-`FormComponent`. The `FormComponent` would need a `setOutputMarkupId(true)` and you need some cutsom javascript to pass the `id` to the behavior.